# Convert Non Columnar Text File to Columnar CSV/Excel

Tags: java, python, regex, csv, text

I have an input text file which contains data extracted from a PDF page by page.
This input text file does not have all the data in column and row format.
How can i convert this to file to a csv or excel with data arranged in column and rows as demonstrated in the picture.
I have attached the sample input file as well as desired sample output file.
Any freeware software or Java/Python ? How should I start ? Any leads for this process is highly appreciated.

Input File and Logic
[image: Input File and Logic]

Output File
[image: Output File]

Input File
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ak0pqpJApp0KlIDxub3txbacTQf_OJOK/view?usp=sharing

Output File
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AiUsyE5lddtfw16OcoU8WNIzFS8yjKOd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you use pdf to excel converter. because my approach here is to convert the pdf to excel. 
after conversion i will rearrange the data to another excel file using python library like (pywin32 ,xlwings or xlswriter)

Comment: Thanks Jasper, I will try to get the original PDF but most likely we will not get the PDF rather the converted text file as attached for the input. I'll try to get the PDF but if it is not feasible, is it possible anyway to do with the input text file we have now ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to basically write a parser. The parsing can be done by basic string operations. The writing to an excel file can then be done by a library like [pandas to excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

## Parsing:

Here are some hopefully helpful tips for parsing:

### [string.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split):

This will allow you to split the text at every space. e.g.

```
>>> "Hello    World".split()
['Hello', 'World']
```

Now when the parts are always at the same indey you can get them by indexing.
To get every line in a separate list you can do for example:

```
text = "Your text you read from the file. \n with some \n newlines \n"
lines = text.split("\n")
```

Suppose you now need some content of line 3:

```
line3 = lines[3]
```

With this, you can now count your indices of lines and whitespaces and can create rules for how you can get what information.

### regular expressions with [re](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re):

If you have a pattern that you can express in a regular expression you can use this module.

for example, you want all dates in format *(dd/mm/yy)*:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "19/02/99 or another date 26/12/12 non valid date 12/12/1999"
>>> re.findall(r"[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}", text)
['19/02/99', '26/12/12', '12/12/19']
```

Other useful functions could be: [search](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.search) or [finditer](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.finditer)

A very useful tool to evaluate and test your regular expressions is: [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

If you have any more questions or want more detailed information about a certain topic, you  are welcome to ask them in the comments.